# Do I need to encrypt the BOXFUSE_SECRET when configuring Travis CI with Boxfuse?

Tags: travis-ci, cloudcaptain

The [Boxfuse Travis CI page](https://cloudcaptain.sh/docs/travisci) says that I need to define two *encrypted Travis CI environment variables* named BOXFUSE_USER and BOXFUSE_SECRET where the BOXFUSE_USER is "Your Boxfuse User" and the BOXFUSE_SECRET is "Your Boxfuse Secret".

So, my first question was, where do I get my Boxfuse Secret? I then found that, when I login to Boxfuse, a *secret* is defined on the **Downloads** page of my Boxfuse account. So, I guess I use that value.

This leads to my second question... Do I need to use the **travis** CLI to encrypt my Boxfuse Secret or do I use my Boxfuse Secret value directly?

I suppose that I need to use the travis CLI to encrypt the Boxfuse Secret since it needs to be encrypted with the Travis public key.

So, I'd like to confirm... I need to use the Boxfuse Secret value that Boxfuse provides on my Boxfuse Download page? And, do I need to encrypt the secret using the Travis CLI?

Answer (score 0):

I confirm the Boxfuse secret is the value you can see on the [Boxfuse Downloads page](https://console.cloudcaptain.sh/#/downloads).

You can encrypt your secret on Travis CI using either [the CLI](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/environment-variables/#defining-encrypted-variables-in-travisyml) or via [the repository settings](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/environment-variables/#defining-variables-in-repository-settings).

Also linking to the Travis CI Boxfuse documentation for reference: https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/deployment/boxfuse/.

Hope this helps!